# How do I run Lucene in Action tests?

Tags: unix, ant, junit, macports

I'm trying to run the [tests of Lucence in Actions](http://www.manning-source.com/books/hatcher2/LuceneInAction.zip) which according to the README should just run with `ant test` , but (oc) this wasn't the case.
When I try I get:

```
check-environment:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/simpatico/Downloads/LuceneInAction/build.xml:53: JUnit not available.  Add junit.jar to ANT_HOME/lib
```

But I do have junit.jar (I symlinked ant-junit.jar and even tried copy-pasting it):

```
ls $ANT_HOME/lib/junit.jar
/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/junit.jar
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: iirc, ant-junit.jar just defines the Ant task for junit.  you need the real junit.jar in $ANT_HOME/lib.  You need to get junit.jar from junit.org.

Comment: @ewh - u r rite, will you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ant-junit.jar just defines the Ant task for junit. you need the real junit.jar in $ANT_HOME/lib. You need to get junit.jar from junit.org.